# Listener for event of dismissed popup and returning primary stage to focus

Tags: java, javafx

I have an primary stage, above of which popup can be shown.
When popup is shown, primary stage is blocked and dont react at any actions.
Popup written in next way:

```
private static Stage chooseBreedStage;
    static {
        chooseBreedStage = new Stage();
        chooseBreedStage.setTitle("Choose breed");
        chooseBreedStage.initOwner(AppKitty.getStage());
        chooseBreedStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        chooseBreedStage.setScene(SceneManager.getInstance().getScene(SceneEnum.CHOOSE_BREED_SCREEN));
    }

    public void showChooseBreedPopup() {
        chooseBreedStage.showAndWait();
    }
```

Is there any way or listener, to handle event, when popup is dismissed, focus returns to primary stage and its fxml file is loaded?
By 'fxml file is loaded' I mean that elements, annotated by @FXML in it's controller not equal null and could be changed

Comment: don't repost a question (in particular not with even less details as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/64960577/203657) - instead edit the previous to make it answerable

Comment: ok, Im just sure that this one is more understandable than previous

Comment: then edit to clarify - repeating: multiple posts of the same question are __not__ an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Modality.WINDOW_MODEL to APPLICATION_MODEL

```
private static Stage chooseBreedStage;
static {
    chooseBreedStage = new Stage();
    chooseBreedStage.setTitle("Choose breed");
    chooseBreedStage.initOwner(AppKitty.getStage());
    chooseBreedStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODEL);
    chooseBreedStage.setScene(SceneManager.getInstance().getScene(SceneEnum.CHOOSE_BREED_SCREEN));
}

public void showChooseBreedPopup() {
    chooseBreedStage.showAndWait();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try at 4 hours and return with result

Comment: It doesnt help, elements inside owner's controller are null, while popup is visible

Comment: please explain.

Comment: Sorry, you answer is correct. My mistake was, that at some point I got controller object by .getConstructor().getInstance() instead FXMLLoader.getController()